# Need to read multiple elements from single line from a text file

Tags: c#, text, split, line

I've tried using Streamwriter, readline, setting var's and if statements with .Contains("stuff"); but I can't get it to print a specific part of the text

```
start ShooterGameServer.exe TheIsland?QueryPort=27015?SessionName=Cain532?MaxPlayers=10?listen?ServerPassword=12345?ServerAdminPassword=******** -nosteamclient -game -server -log
```

I need to read the stuff after "SessionName", "MaxPlayers", "ServerPassword","ServerAdminPassword"

I can't figure out how to make Split work with it either :(

I have 3 textboxes and a numericupdown box I need to plug the values into.

Comment: wha texactly do you want to print?

Comment: Please explain more specifically in what way you _"can't figure out how to make Split work"_. Provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a detailed explanation of what the code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the C# string.Split() method to separate out what you need.

```
        string input = "start ShooterGameServer.exe TheIsland?QueryPort=27015?SessionName=Cain532?MaxPlayers=10?listen?ServerPassword=12345?ServerAdminPassword=******** -nosteamclient -game -server -log";
        string[] parts = input.Split('?', ' '); // Split string by '?' and ' '
        string output = "";
        foreach(var part in parts)
        {
            if(part.StartsWith("ServerAdminPassword")) // Put what you are looking for here
                output = part.Split('=')[1]; // Get right side of '='
        }
        Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: I am glad I was able to help! Would anyone mind telling me why this is downvoted though? If there is an issue here maybe the OP should know about it.

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted :( I fixed that tho! Sorry I'm still pretty new to StackOverflow :P Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you only need to  parse the string from the first parameter.

You can just split your query string using '?' as separator. Then split the resulting strings by '=' and assign them to anonymous object with `Name` and `Value' properties, with`Value` defaulting to, say, an empty string if a particular parameter doesn't have any value:

```
var queryString = "TheIsland?QueryPort=27015?SessionName=Cain532?MaxPlayers=10?listen?ServerPassword=12345?ServerAdminPassword=********";
var result = queryString
    .Split('?')
    .Select(p => p.Split('=')
    .Select(d => new {Name = d[0], Value= d.Count() >=2 ? d[1] : string.Empty});
var sessionNameParam = result.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == "SessionName");
if (sessionNameParam != null) {
    var sessionNameValue = sessionNameParam.Value;
}
var maxPlayersParam = result.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == "MaxPlayers");
if (maxPlayersParam != null) {
    var maxPlayersValue = maxPlayersParam.Value;
}
```

If you need to do it on a regular basis, you can create a small utility class.

Comment: Down-voting without a reason is kind of pointless, don't you think, anonymous down-voter?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can read the string from the text file and now you need to retrieve the informations that you have in it. Try ***.Split()*** to separate your required string and retrieve the corresponding informations.

```
        string fileContent = @"start ShooterGameServer.exe TheIsland? QueryPort=27015?SessionName=Cain532?MaxPlayers=10?listen?ServerPassword=12345?ServerAdminPassword=******** -nosteamclient -game -server -log";
        Dictionary<string, string> content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string selectedSection = fileContent.Split(' ')[2];
        foreach (var singleOption in selectedSection.Split('?'))
        {
            if (singleOption.Split('=').Length == 2)
            {
                content.Add(singleOption.Split('=')[0], singleOption.Split('=')[1]);                    
            }
        }
```

To get your required value use appropriate key from ***content*** with a foreach loop.

```
        foreach (var singleContent in content)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(singleContent.Key + " : " + singleContent.Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way (if the general format of the text remains the same):

```
var @params =
    text
        .Split(' ')[2]
        .Split('?')
        .Skip(1)
        .Where(x => x.Contains("="))
        .Select(x => x.Split('='))
        .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

That gives me this dictionary:

[image: parameters]

Comment: It appears we have a rampant down-voter. Everyone got a down-vote. I can't see why. Have we all missed something in the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

```
str.Split(' ')[2].Split('?').Where(l => l.Split('=').Length > 1).ToList().ForEach(item =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} && {1}", item.Split('=')[0], item.Split('=')[1]);
            });
```